# angular dropdown submenu works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I have couple bugs in my dropdown menu which I can't resolve.

1. Ng-repeat set same submenu for each element in parent dropdown menu even if I try to restrict it thru scope function or filter
2. Function every time loads the last object from array.

[this is my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Rn5jN3a2nLD6UQhxgst?p=preview)

and my code

html

```
<div class="dropdown category" style="position:relative">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="entity in entitis" >
           <a class="trigger right-caret">{{ entity }}</a>
   <ul ng-if="entity | filter : 'Main'" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
         <li ng-repeat="domain in ast" ng-click="getDomain()">
            <a href=""> {{domain.name}}</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
{{ items }}
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'Reinforcement';

  $scope.entitis = ["Main", "Submain", "Class"];

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.entitis.length; i++){
                if ($scope.entitis[i] == "Main"){
                    $http.get('ast.json')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            $scope.ast = response.data;
                            console.log($scope.ast);
                        });
                }
            }

      $scope.getDomain = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ast.length; i++) {
               $scope.items = $scope.ast[i].children
            }
         }


        $(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
            var current=$(this).next();
            var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
            if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
                $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
            current.toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
            var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
            root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
        });
    });

});
```

I appreciate any help or advice

Comment: Did not quite get question 2. Which function loads what? and what is expected

Comment: And to solve #1, you need `<ul ng-if="entity == 'Main'" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">` filters work on `ng-repeat` and not `ng-if`

Comment: oh, it was pretty simple, thanks! about second, please wait a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how it works. **[this is working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tj0cMMDxtOMdrl6f6QZj?p=preview)**

and code

js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'Reinforcement';

  $scope.entitis = ["Main", "Submain", "Class"];

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.entitis.length; i++){
                if ($scope.entitis[i] == "Main"){
                    $http.get('ast.json')
                         .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.ast = data;
                        });
                }
            }

      $scope.getDomain = function (index) {
           console.info($scope.ast[index].name);
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ast.length; i++) {
               $scope.items = $scope.ast[index].children
            }
         }


        $(function(){
        $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
            var current=$(this).next();
            var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
            if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
                $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
            current.toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
            var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
            root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
            root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
        });
    });


});
```

html

```
<div class="dropdown category" style="position:relative">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="entity in entitis" >
                                            <a class="trigger right-caret">{{ entity }}</a>
                                            <ul ng-if="entity == 'Main'" class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                                                <li ng-repeat="domain in ast" ng-click="getDomain($index)">
                                                    <a href=""> {{domain.name}}</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                {{ items }}
```